# Python string to classes

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, printing

Can we change the output of class string? note: I am talking about class not instance

for example:

```
class Foo(object):
    baz=10
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value=value

    def bar(self):
        self.a="3llo world"

    def __str__(self):
        return "not me"

    def __repr__(self):
        return "not me either"

print Foo
```

output:

```
<class '__main__.Foo'>
```

where does the output come from? thanks

Comment: In the duplicate you'll see the answer is to simply definie `__str__` on the metaclass

Comment: I think that because the class you declared is `Foo` and when you type `print Foo`, it will return a kind of `class` object. About the class string, I think that you can't because class is something abstract and you cannot call a class to do something. Check my thought if I am wrong!

Comment: @PhucTran That is what OP wants, just to change the text in that case

Comment: @PhucTran You are wrong, click on the duplicate and you can see its possible

Comment: please close as duplication. thank you for jamylak